# Texture R8_FLOAT format?

Tags: directx, directx11

I'm working on SAO (http://graphics.cs.williams.edu/papers/SAOHPG12/) and I want to store my ambient obscurance term (a value between 0.0 and 1.0) in a texture.

When I did shadowmapping, I created my depth-texture as `DXGI_FORMAT_R32_TYPELESS` and the shader resoure view as `DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT`, however with this I want a `DXGI_FORMAT_R8_TYPELESS` format and a `FLOAT` equivalent, yet there appears to be none according to the docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173059(v=vs.85).aspx)

1) What texture/srv/rtv format should I use if I want to store/read/write 8-bit float values?

2) Does the format used really matter? Does directx do any behind-the-scenes alterations to the texture data? Is a `DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UNORM` treated differently from a `DXGI_FORMAT_R8_SNORM` for example?

Comment: 8-bit floats would have an extremely low precision. Are you sure you want an 8-bit float? `DXGI_FORMAT_U8_UNORM` is what you want if you do indeed need an 8-bit value (and yes, that's different than an `SNORM`, in that the former maps [0,256) to [0, 1.0] while the later maps [-128,+128) to [-1.0,+1.0]).

Comment: for the purpose of storing a ambient obscurance term, perhaps R16 float is enough?

Answer (score 1):

The smallest single float supported by DirectX 11.x is `DXGI_FORMAT_R16_FLOAT` which requires [Feature Level 10.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc627090.aspx) or better hardware. The smallest single float supported by Feature Level 9.x is `DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT`.

If you can require Feature Level 10.0+ or better hardware, a better choice might be to use `DXGI_FORMAT_R11G11B10_FLOAT` or `DXGI_FORMAT_R9G9B9E5_SHAREDEXP` if you can live with the limitations of those formats.